# How to save checkbox choice in wordpress

Tags: theme-development, input

I know that i should use update_post_meta() function but don't know where put it in the code. I tried on the diferent ways but it's don't work how it should.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'noo_render_location_picker_field' ) ) :
    function noo_render_location_picker_field( $field = array(), $field_id = '', $value = '', $form_type = '', $object = array() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'location-picker' );

        $post_id  = ! empty( $object ) ? $object['ID'] : 0;
        $input_id = $field_id;
        $class    = isset( $field['required'] ) && $field['required'] ? 'class="noo-mb-location-address form-control jform-validate" required aria-required="true"' : ' class="noo-mb-location-address form-control"';

        $address = noo_get_post_meta( $post_id, $field_id, '' );
        $lat     = noo_get_post_meta( $post_id, $field_id . '_lat', '' );
        $lon     = noo_get_post_meta( $post_id, $field_id . '_lon', '' );

        $is_frontend_submit = ( isset( $_GET['action'] ) && $_GET['action'] == 'post_job' ) ? true : false;
        $is_edit_job = ( isset( $_GET['job_id'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['job_id'] ) ) ? true : false;
        $checkbox_label = __( 'The same as company address', 'noo' );
        $checkbox_id    = '_use_company_address';
        $company_id         = jm_get_employer_company();
        $full_address_company   = ! empty( $company_id ) ? get_post_meta( $company_id, '_full_address', true ) : '';
        $checkbox_value = empty( $post_id ) ? 1 : get_post_meta( $post_id, $checkbox_id, true );

        if ( ($is_frontend_submit && !empty($full_address_company) ) or (!empty($full_address_company) && $is_edit_job)):

            ?>
            <input name="<?php echo $checkbox_id; ?>" type="hidden" value="0"/>
            <div class="form-control-flat">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input id="use_company_address" name="<?php echo $checkbox_id; ?>" type="checkbox" <?php checked( $checkbox_value ); ?> value="1"/><i></i>
                    <?php echo esc_html( $checkbox_label ); ?>
                </label>
            </div>
            <script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                    jQuery("#use_company_address").change(function () {
                        if (jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
                            jQuery(".noo-location-picker-field-wrap").addClass('hidden');
                        } else {
                            jQuery(".noo-location-picker-field-wrap").removeClass('hidden');
                        }
                    }).change();
                });
            </script>

        <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="noo-location-picker-field-wrap <?php echo $checkbox_value ? '' : ''; ?>">
                <input <?php echo $class; ?> type="text" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_id ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_html($address); ?>" placeholder="<?php echo esc_html__('Enter an exact address.', 'noo') ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" class="noo-mb-lat" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_id ) ?>_lat" value="<?php echo $lat; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" class="noo-mb-lon" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_id ) ?>_lon" value="<?php echo $lon; ?>">
                <div class="noo-mb-job-location" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_id ); ?>" data-lat="<?php echo $lat; ?>"
                     data-lon="<?php echo $lon; ?>" style="height: 300px;">
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
    }
endif;
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly, you are not able to save using update_post_meta. If this is you can try saving using jQuery using ajax, try this.

```
 //on change checkbox
  jQuery.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=your_custom_function",
     data:{
         meta_id: 'YOUR_META_ID', //get user or post meta and set here
         meta_value: 'YOUR_META_VALUE' /the value you want to save in the meta
     },
     dataType: 'JSON',
     success: function(res)
     {
        console.log(res);
     }
  });

  //in your functions.php
  function your_custom_function(){
      return (get_post_meta($_POST['meta_id'], 'you_meta_name')) ? update_post_meta($_POST['meta_id'], 'you_meta_name', $_POST['meta_value']) : ($_POST['meta_id'], 'you_meta_name', $_POST['meta_value'], true);
  }
  add_action('wp_ajax_your_custom_function','your_custom_function');
```

So each time the checkbox is changed, your goal will be updated, you can debug it using the console's XHR.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: You may want to *sanitize* the `$_POST` input. As shown, your code accepts everything and is *highly insecure*!